# Search for an Item inside an Dojo Store

Tags: dojo

Is there any way to find an "item" inside an Dojo Store (Version 1.1!!).

The Format of the Json Data is like: name/id.

So far if tryed it with:

```
var storeItem = this.myFilteringSelect.store.fetch({query: {name: "Alpha"}});
```

But fetch does not return the item?  Btw. i need the "ID" of the Item to set an default value for the filteringSelect (but the id can change from time to time...)

Comment: Have you tried var storeItem = this.myFilteringSelect.store.fetch({query: {name: *}});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me preface my answer in that I can't speak to 1.1 specifically. But in 1.6...

`store.fetch` is coded in an asynchronous manner.  It does not return the item.  You must provide a callback that will iterate over the items returned from the query.

```
store.fetch({
    query: {/*queryParams*/},
    onComplete: function(items, findResult){
        dojo.forEach(items, function(item){
            // work with your item
        }
    }
});
```

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dojo/data/api/Read.html#dojo-data-api-read

I don't believe this API had changed much over time, so if it is present in 1.1, then I think this should help.

Comment: Thanks works with 1.6+ :-) But not with this old stuff. I found an other "unelegant" solutions for my problem, so i will accept your answer for others using "newer" versions of dojO!